# LINQ. NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Unit of Work:

```
public class UnitOfWork :  IUnitOfWork
{
    private Forum_dbEntities context;
    private bool isDisposed;

    public UnitOfWork(IForumtDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context as Forum_dbEntities;
    }

    public DbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class
    {
        return this.context.Set<T>();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.isDisposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                this.context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.isDisposed = true;
    }


    public int Save()
    {
        return this.context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public EntityState Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        return this.context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

Метод возвращающий словарь с IDтопика(key) и кол-вом в нем сообщений(value)

```
 public Dictionary<int, int> GetMessagesCount()
    {

        Dictionary<int, int> messagesCount = this.unitOfWork.Set<Topic>()
            .Select(t => new
            {
                Key = t.TopicID,
                Value = this.unitOfWork.Set<Message>()
                .Count<Message>(count => count.TopicID == t.TopicID)
            })
            .ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Value);

        return messagesCount;
    }
```

Однако `this.unitOfWork.Set<Message>().Count<Message>(count => count.TopicID == t.TopicID)`
выдает ошибку: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet 1[Core.EntityModel.Message] Set[Message]()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

В чем может быть проблема? Когда учился делать проект без UoW, напрямую юзал `context` работало все нормально.

w/o UoW:

```
 public Dictionary<int, int> GetMessagesCount()
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> messagesCount = context.Topics
            .Select(t => new
            {
                Key = t.TopicID,
                Value = context.Messages
                .Count(count => count.TopicID == t.TopicID)
            })
            .ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Value);

        return messagesCount;
    }
```

Comment: а какой код был без использования?

Comment: @Grundy `Value = context.Messages.Count(count => count.TopicID == t.TopicID)`

Comment: @Grundy было свойство  `private Forum_dbEntities context`, в конструкторе инициализировал его

Comment: @Grundy  добавил весь метод без UoW

Comment: попробуй без `UoW`: `Value = context.Set<Messages>()` - ту же ошибку получишь, что и сейчас?

Comment: @Grundy Ошибки нету

Comment: при использовании Set напрямую нет ошибки?

Comment: @grundy да ошибки нету

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо вынести вложенный LINQ-запрос, либо выгрузить данные. Вот пример вынесенного запроса:

```
public Dictionary<int, int> GetMessagesCount()
{
    var data = this.unitOfWork.Set<Message>();
    Dictionary<int, int> messagesCount = this.unitOfWork.Set<Topic>().ToList()
        .Select(t => new
        {
            Key = t.TopicID,
            Value = data.Count(count => count.TopicID == t.TopicID)
        })
        .ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Value);

    return messagesCount;
}
```

Получается, что он пытается преобразовать внутренний запрос, но нельзя построить SQL запрос на основе этого кода из-за отсутствия значений, используемых внутри запроса. Сначала нужно получить данные, а потом использовать их внутри LINQ для построения запроса.

Comment: `ToList` можно было вызвать и не вынося. Ну и синтаксическая ошибка в примере `;.`

Comment: @Grundy, вынести нужно, так как во время каждого обращения будет строиться запрос и получаться данные, а так только один раз. Да, после `;` забыл код убрать.

Comment: @DenisBuhov `Unable to create a constant value of type Core.EntityModel.Message. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`.

Comment: @Jitsu, это в какой строке появилась? Просто не могу Ваш код отладить...

Comment: @DenisBuhov  все там же, где начинается запрос

Comment: @Jitsu, попробуйте `ToList()`добавить перед `Select`

Comment: @DenisBuhov все заработало, если можно, объясните ошибку и ее решение: ToList()/toArray

Comment: @Jitsu, дело в том, что `DbSet` возвращает `IQueryable`. То есть данные Вы не получили, а только запрос. У Вас использовался вложенный запрос - но такие запросы не поддерживаются. Вторая ошибка говорит о том, что тип данных внутри предиката слишком сложный и Linq не справляется с преобразованием. А когда мы используем `ToList()/ToArray` - мы получаем `IEnumerable`, то есть выгружаем в память данные, а не формируем запрос.

Comment: @DenisBuhov  спасибо